Solution of $x=0$ for $\frac{4 x^2 (5 + x)}{20 x + 4 x^2} = 2 x$?
The equation in question here is $\frac{4x^{2}\left(5+x\right)}{20x+4x^{2}}=2x$.
Why does Mathematica (13.1) return x->0 for this? The left side is undefined at zero.
Solve[(4 x^2 (5 + x))/(20 x + 4 x^2) == 2 x]

Interestingly, Wolfram Alpha gets it right with:
(no solutions exist)

The left side is undefined at zero. If you do this lhs=(4 u^2 (5+u))/(20 u+4 u^2); rhs=2*x; Solve[lhs==rhs,x] then you get x -> u/2 now what happens when u=0? you get x->0

0 is what's called a removable singularity in that quotient.

It does not say x==0, now does it?

Mathematica 14 does the same. It looks like it is simplified first, so it solves x == 2x for x.
(4  x^2  (5 + x))/(20  x + 4  x^2) // Simplify

(* x *)


Here is some justification for MMA answer:
a=(4  x^2  (5 + x))/(20  x + 4  x^2);
Limit[a, x->0]
Plot[{a,2x},{x,-1,1}]
Solve[a==2x,x]


